# Specifying the encoding when saving a file in a Windows app

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, file, character-encoding

I am writing a program that handles mostly Unicode text. The C standard library function 'fopen' provides for writing the characters to file in utf-8 format by including in the mode string argument "..., ccs=utf-8". It seems that the Windows API 'CreateFile' does give such provision. Must I use 'fopen' then?

Comment: `CreateFile` creates a file, as the name implies. It doesn't write data to it. You need a different function for that. I'm not really sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is Specific to programming under Windows, using Visual Studio, and Microsoft tools. My personal advice is to not to use fopen with the extended syntax, otherwise later there will be compatibility issues when porting your application to other operating systems. When under Windows, do the Windows way, use CreateFile.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the file are defined not by the file-opening function, but the actual data you write. After you get the file handle (either by fopen or CreateFile), you can write in UTF-8, or ANSI, or whatever you like.

Note that some encodings require a special bit at the beginning of the file.

Comment: What makes 'fopen' convenient really is that I can assign a 16-bit value to a wchar_t variable and write it directly to the file opened with utf-8 encoding. That 16-bit Unicode value may extend to 24 bits when encoded in utf-8 but it gets written without any fuss at all. I don't bother either with special bits like BOM or such. I have written simple programs like that in Windows and Linux. Identical code. Worked alike.